# Cracked formica backsplash 'curve' repair/reinforcement

Tags: repair, crack, countertops

Due to a massive and sudden water leak it was necessary to remove the cabinets. In doing so (removing the sink) I discovered the Previous Owner (PO) used an entire tube of caulk to secure it.

The removal process ended up cracking the curved portion of the backsplash on the countertop. There was no reinforcement behind it, leading me to believe it was just bent and pushed near the 90 degree.
I could inject low expansion foam (would be hard) or push in epoxy/acrylic to firm up and reinforce the spot.
It is right behind the sink that will be put in, so water proof is more of a concern than most.

Suggestions? Replacement of the entire countertop is not an option at this time.

Edit: Foam suggestion would be to drill a 1/4" hole (size of nozzle) into the back of the wood near the crack and blow a couple of low expansion foam shots in there, hoping to fill it in.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? Did you use Gil's suggestion? If so, please click the check mark on his answer so others know. If not, maybe consider adding a picture or two to your post so others might have a better idea of what's going on and be able to offer suggestions.

Comment: I did not. I ended up 'sealing' the area with silicone and showing/incorporating daily pat downs. I could not get the seams to lay properly unfortunately. I did forget to upvote tho- thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a good start. Be sure you thoroughly clean the surrounding area  with acetone (it is highly flammable be sure the room is well ventilated) applied it with a rag or sponge, a paper towel makes a mess. Squeeze a small amount of laminate filler or paste that matches your Formica counter onto the edge of a stainless steel putty knife. Apply the filler to the damaged area using your putty knife, filling the crack completely. There are many different brands of filler available. This one caught my eye: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tf3voZ4J1gg it is a video showing how to use it. This stuff is generally used on the top but I see no reason it cannot be used on the backsplash.